# Terraform for_each template for "current" key

Tags: terraform, google-artifact-registry

Given the following code:

```
locals {
  registry_flat = merge(flatten([
    for registry, roles in var.iam_members : [
      for role, members in roles : {
        for member in members :
        "${registry}-${role}-${member}" => {
          registry = registry
          role     = role
          member   = member
        }
      }
    ]
  ])...)
}

resource "google_artifact_registry_repository_iam_member" "member" {

  for_each = local.registry_flat

  location   = var.region
  repository = each.value.registry
  role       = each.value.role
  member     = each.value.member
}
```

And the following variables:

```
variable "iam_members" {
  type = map(map(list(string)))
  default = {
    "registry01" = {
      "roles/artifactregistry.reader" = ["user:aaa@aaaaa.aa"]
    },
    "registry02" = {
      "roles/artifactregistry.admin" = ["user:qqq@qqqq.qq"],
      "roles/artifactregistry.reader" = ["user:aaa@aaaaa.aa"]
    }
  }
}
```

One resource "google_artifact_registry_repository_iam_member" will generate for each combination of registry/role/principal.

Problem comes when the registry has still not been created, then applying the IAM for that particular registry fails.

Because of this, I think I would need to add a depends_on statement on the generated iam_member resource, so each one of them, depends on the particular registry for which is being created.

That approach, i'm failing to implement. How that could be done?